# How to connect vercel frontend deployment to backend deployed on aws ec2 instance

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ec2, deployment, vercel

The backend is correctly deployed on a specific port in ec2 instance but it's http. But the frontend is deployed on vercel which uses https and I face the mixed content error. So how do I convert the backend server to https?

I had trouble deploying the frontend is deployed because of the nginx configuration issues, hence why i decided to use vercel

I do have a public DNS server link to this ec2 instance but its not responsive when i run Django server.

I want the backend deployed to connect to the frontend either using ec2 instance or vercel.

The backend deployment is working with ec2 instance but how do i connect it to frontend deployment?

Answer (score 1):

I m also facing same issue unable to debug yet i think to make it work we might need to use subdomain for backend and main domain which will look for forntend over vercel.. cause when i m trying it's saying that it's already been used by some other website which is vercel.. using the http(80) and https(443) over the frontend.. i m gonna try with subdomain..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).